# Identification of a singular plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

Can anyone tell me the identity of this plant?

1. [image: List item]

Comment: My guess would be nicotinia; typically white or pink flowers.

Comment: Bell pepper perhaps, or some kind of pepper. The alternate leaf arrangement and shape. If it has small white bell-shaped flowers, that would be more certain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any clues? How did it get in the pot? Did you buy it? If so, what sort of plants, in general, have you purchased recently?

If you bought vegetable starts and lost the tag, it looks like it might be a pepper. It would be impossible to identify what variety based on its current state!

But without some clues and history, it could be lots of other things, too!